# qpixmap qclipboard and save image inverted

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

**Environment:**

Qt 4.7, Mac OS X 10.12.6

**Problem:**

When I save an image, or place it in the clipboard and then paste it under OS X 10.12.6 from an application built with Qt 4.7, the resulting image is inverted vertically. I am using `native` graphics mode, because OS X 10.12 has broken Qt 4.7 tooltips for the `raster` mode; the save and copy to clipboard functions have worked properly for years from 10.6.8 up to 10.11, so in those OS X versions I do use `raster`. In that case, the clipboard images (and saved images) are not inverted.

*Here is what I am doing for copy to clipboard:*

```
QPixmap pm = QPixmap::grabWindow(uiframePlot->winId());
clipboard->setPixmap( pm, QClipboard::Clipboard);
QApplication::processEvents();
```

*Here is what I am doing for save image:*

```
QString qs = QDir::homePath() + scappath;
QPixmap pm = QPixmap::grabWindow(uiframePlot->winId());
pm.save(qs);
```

I have attempted to locate a "flip pixmap" function, but have had no luck. My Google-fu may be deficient here. I've hunted for "invert", "flip" and "transform" with "Qt 4.7"

Can anyone offer a pointer to a native (meaning, standard part of a Qt class) Qt-based, "flip" function for a pixmap? Or do I need to write one?

Comment: you might be interested in the QImage::mirrored() function which can flip an image horizontally or vertically. Unfortunately there is no QPixmap version but QPixmaps can be converted to QImages pretty easily using QPixmap::toImage()

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that seems to work okay:

```
QPixmap pm = QPixmap::grabWindow(tmw->ui->frameScope->winId());
if (imageinvert)
{
    QPixmap pmf = pm.transformed(QTransform().scale(1, -1));
    clipboard->setPixmap( pmf, QClipboard::Clipboard);
}
else
{
    clipboard->setPixmap( pm, QClipboard::Clipboard);
}
QApplication::processEvents();
```